# How to clear values from the DynamicForm PnP SpFx control?

Tags: spfx-webparts

I am using the DynamicForm control in my SpFX webpart from @pnp/spfx-controls-react. I want to clear the current values in the form when the user either a) adds a new item to the list, or b) clicks the cancel button.

Is there a good way to do this?

Here is the definition of my Dynamic Form:

```
<DynamicForm 
    context={this.props.context} 
    listId={this.state.listId} 
    onSubmitted={async () => { this.getItems(5); this.setState({formIsOpened: false}); }}
    onCancelled={() => { this.setState({formIsOpened: false}); }} 
/>
```

There are only 2 fields, Title and Description. My form only allows users to add new Items, not to edit existing items. So once the form is submitted or cancelled, I just want to clear the text boxes.

Thanks!